# Vue.js - named slots

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a beginner question about named slots. In my example, I want to display just the content for the first slot - but it's not working unless I use `<slot></slot>` without `name="first"`. What's wrong with my example?

```js
Vue.component('user-name', {
  props: ['name'],
  template: `
        <p slot="first">Hi {{ name }}</p>
            `
});

Vue.component('user-nickname', {
  props: ['name'],
  template: `
             <p slot="secont">Byee {{ name }}</p>
            `
});

Vue.component('user-information', {
  template: `<div class="user-information">
          <slot name="first"></slot>        
              </div>
             `,
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
body{
  width:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  color: blue;
  
}

.user-information {
  background: red;
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <user-information>
      <user-name name="Foo"></user-name>
      <user-nickname name="Boo"></user-nickname>
    </user-information>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `slot="..whatever.."` from your components. Then add a second named slot to `user-information`. Finally in your main reference the slot as the parent of your sub-components

```
<user-information>
    <template v-slot:first>
        <user-name name="Foo"></user-name>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:second>
        <user-nickname name="Boo"></user-nickname>
    </template>
</user-information>
```